# Converting a Datetime to string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, dotnethighcharts

Im new to C#. Im trying to create a line chart using DotNet High Chart in MVC5. I am trying to use Date which is a DateTime, from a database. I need to convert DateTime to a string in order for it to populate in High Chart

```
var iOPLeftCount = (from d in db.Appointments
                    where d.PatientId == p.PatientId
                    select d).Count();


// modify the data type to array type
var xDataDate = iOPLeftCount.Select(i => i.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")).ToArray();
var yDataIOPLeft = iOPLeftCount.Select(i => new object[] { i.IOPLeft }).ToArray();
```

However I am getting the following error with the above code

> int does not contain a definition for select accepting a first
>   arguement of type int could be found

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Count` returns `int`. That's why your `iOPLeftCount` is integer. You can't use `Select` with it.

Comment: Try deleting `.Count()`, then it will return an object where the `PatientId` is like the specified ID.

Comment: There is not enough information here to solve your question. Can you post the relevant data types (class structures)?

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the date conversion. It is because you are calling `.Count()`, which returns an `int`, and then using `.Select` on that.

It is not too clear what you are trying to achieve, but I guess something like this:

```
var data = (from d in db.Appointments
            where d.PatientId == p.PatientId
            select new 
            {
                Date = d.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"),
                IOPLeft = d.IOPLeft,
            }).ToList();

var xSeries = data.Select(a => a.Date).ToArray();
var ySeries = data.Select(a => a.IOPLeft).ToArray();
```

```